# Store array custom array information

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a doubt when it comes to store array information, this is my API

```
WalletService.shared.getSiteDetails { siteDetails, error in
                
            }
```

***siteDetails*** is going to give me the decodeJson information,
one of multiple information that is retrieving is

```
public let fuelGrades: [MBFuelGrades]?
```

Which contains this

```
public struct MBFuelGrades: Codable {
    public let fuelType: String?
    public let price: Double?
    public let priceTier: String?
}
```

so when my API call response I get this array by printing
it could contain multiple elements not only one

```
po siteDetails?.fuelGrades
▿ Optional<Array<MBFuelGrades>>
  ▿ some : 1 element
    ▿ 0 : MBFuelGrades
      ▿ fuelType : Optional<String>
        - some : "REGULAR"
      ▿ price : Optional<Double>
        - some : 1.339
      ▿ priceTier : Optional<String>
        - some : "CREDIT"
```

what I trying to do is store the  `fuelType` and `price`, in separate arrays

for example this:

```
var fuelGradesTypes: [String] = [""]
var fuelGradesPrice: [Double] = [0.0]
```

my question is how can I store this elements inside the arrays?
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to separate your data into two arrays, that is often a bad idea that makes it harder to access the data in a correct way? Slightly unrelated but why is everything optional in your struct, unless the value from the api can be null having optional properties for no reason  is another way of making your code more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
guard let grades = siteDetails.fuelGrades else { return }

fuelGradesTypes = grades.compactMap { $0.fuelType }
fuelGradesPrice = grades.compactMap { $0.price }
```

Comment: thanks for replying! it gives me this error on `fuelType`
Cannot assign value of type 'U?' to type '[String]'

Comment: fuelGrades doesn't always came from the json response